# @Autowired are giving Null Pointer Exceptions in SpringBoot CXF application

Tags: soap, spring-boot, cxf, autowired

I have created a SpringBoot CXF soap service from an existing WSDL file. I can now access WSDL from my service running on embedded tomcat from the springboot application. When I am trying to send a request to the service from soap-ui, the control reaches the implementation of the service method and then while it access the @Autowired service layer, it throws all NPE, as the service object is null (I have seen this while debugging). If I manually create (new Service() by commenting out the @Autowired object), the flow can reach the service implementation and then the DAO object fails as it cannot @Autowire the DAO Impl, further when i create the manually DAO Impl object it fails at @PersistenceContext, as it the entity manager is null.

I have made sure service is annotated with @Service, DAO layer with @Repository, still the issue persists. Also i have added @ComponentScan and giving all the package names, still i am getting null for all @Autowired.

Code below: Configuration class

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class EmWebSvcBootApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer{

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(EmWebSvcBootApplication.class, args);
}

public static final String SERVICE_NAME_URL_PATH = "/em";
public static final String EM_ISSUER_SERVICE_NAME_URL_PATH = "/EntitlementIssuer";


@Bean(name=Bus.DEFAULT_BUS_ID)
public SpringBus springBus() {      
    return new SpringBus();
}


@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean cxfServlet() {
    ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistrationBean = new ServletRegistrationBean(new CXFServlet(), SERVICE_NAME_URL_PATH + "/*");
    // Add custom Title to CXF´s ServiceList
    Map<String, String> initParameters = servletRegistrationBean.getInitParameters();
    initParameters.put("service-list-title", "My Test service");
    return servletRegistrationBean;
}

@Bean
public Endpoint endpoint() {
    EndpointImpl endpoint = new EndpointImpl(springBus(), new EntitlementIssuerEndpointImpl());
    endpoint.setServiceName(entitlementIssuer_Service().getServiceName());
    endpoint.setWsdlLocation(entitlementIssuer_Service().getWSDLDocumentLocation().toString());
    endpoint.publish(EM_ISSUER_SERVICE_NAME_URL_PATH);
    return endpoint;
}

 @Bean EntitlementIssuer_Service entitlementIssuer_Service(){
     return new  EntitlementIssuer_Service();
 }
```

}

Service class:

```
@Service
public class EntitlementIssuerServiceImpl implements EntitlementIssuerService {

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EntitlementIssuerServiceImpl.class);

@Autowired
private EntitlementIssuerDAO entitlementIssuerDAO;

@Transactional(readOnly=true)
public List<EntitlementIssuerResponseWrapper> getEntitlementIssuers(EntitlementIssuerRequestWrapper requestWrapper)
        throws EMSystemException, EMBusinessException {

try{
            daoResponse = entitlementIssuerDAO.findEntitlementIssuers(requestWrapper);
        }catch(Throwable t){
        logger.error("Error while getting entitlement issuers: " + t.getMessage());
        throw new EMSystemException("Error while getting entitlement issuers: " + t.getMessage());
    }

}
```

DAO layer:

```
@Repository
public class EntitlementIssuerDaoImpl implements EntitlementIssuerDAO{

    @PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;

public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
    return entityManager;
}

@Override
public List<EntitlementIssuer> findEntitlementIssuers(EntitlementIssuerRequestWrapper request) {

    Session session = (Session) entityManager.getDelegate();
    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(EntitlementIssuer.class, "entitlementIssuer");

    setupCriteria(request,criteria);
    List<EntitlementIssuer> output = criteria.list();
    return output;

}
}
```

pom.xml

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <em.wsdl.version>2.2.0</em.wsdl.version>
    <cxf.version>3.1.7</cxf.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Apache CXF -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
```

I have added all the configurations that i am using, any help to fix this is highly appreciated. Basically all the @Autowired services, data layers, and entity managers are not loaded (as i see them as null in the debug).

Comment: You are creating your own, unmanaged instance of `EntitlementIssuerEndpointImpl`...

Comment: Thanks a lot M.Deinum  for finding this issue,  I'm totally ignorant of this issue. It is working fine now. Again many thanks. Changed the implementation to be a spring managed bean.                                                         @Bean
    public EntitlementIssuerEndpointImpl getEntitlementIssuerEndpointImpl(){
     return new EntitlementIssuerEndpointImpl();
    }

Comment: Do you mind sharing your fixed code here? Whenever i call my autowired class method within the service class i get a cxf nulpointer error and im still not able to figure out why... thanks in advqnced

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to fix the issue based on the info from https://github.com/codecentric/cxf-spring-boot-starter

```
/**
 * Configuration of SOAP Web services
 */
@Configuration
public class EntitlementIssuerServiceSOAPConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Bus bus;

    @Bean
    public EntitlementIssuerService getEntitlementIssuerServiceWebServiceImpl() {
        return new EntitlementIssuerServiceWebServiceImpl();
    }

    @Bean (name = "EntitlementIssuerServiceWebService")
    public Endpoint endpoint() {
        EndpointImpl endpoint = new EndpointImpl(bus, getEntitlementIssuerServiceWebServiceImpl());
        endpoint.publish("/EntitlementIssuerService");
        return endpoint;
    }

}
```